# CSS or javascript - How to fix appearance whilst browsers have different DPI/zoom settings?

Tags: javascript, css

I just updated to Firefox 22. They have changed some DPI code which makes everything appear slightly too large/zoomed in for some OSs like windows 7 if you are using certain resolution settings. You can fix this by making changes to the about:config CSS for firefox itself- thats fine, but 99% of people aren't going to bother.

I was reading up on some of the BOM and DOM and there is an ability to detect browser resolutions and things. So is there a way to detect the relative positions of elements on the screen/font sizes, and then using javascript re-scale and force the webpage to display exactly as intended? For usability, I could have an option for users to ignore this feature (for visually impaired, etc...).

Comment: IMNSHO it's a waste of your time to try and chase this.  I give it 50/50 odds that they'll change it back in the next revision, and your effort will have been wasted.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, it really pisses me off- you work you're ass off to optimise a site with images at the exact sizes for the display to save badnwidth/loading time, and spend ages tinkering with CSS, then in one instant 50% of all your site's users have blurry/awkward/ugly pages to look at...

Comment: "certain resolution settings" - Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Šime Vidas here:http://www.ghacks.net/2013/06/24/firefox-22-0-find-out-what-is-new/

Comment: @user1166981 Where in that article is the relevant info?

Comment: @Šime Vidas, please use google, it isn't hard to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than detect browser resolutions, I might try to simply branch on browser types and versions. Might turn out a little lengthy, but could be a good hack for the immediate resolution issue.

```
 var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 
 var version = new RegExp("MSIE 10"); //for IE
      if(version.test(ua))
      {
         // do one thing.
      }    
      else
      {
          // do the other thing.
      }
```